# Store Landing Page

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, cms, phpstorm

I have 3 stores under a website. I want to create a website Landing page that allow to choose the store website.

When any user land on the website by default it should display on the Store View Landing Page(Full View) and from there he/she choose there store. 
I have already create the store Landing page with different views.